# URL re-written with a -1

Tags: redirect

https://theidleman.com/brands/carhartt-1.html
has been generated in addition to our old https://theidleman.com/brands/carhartt.html URL - how can I delete the '-1' and redirect it if the '-1' does not show in Catergories?

Thank you,

TIM

Answer (score 0):

That `-1` gets added by the URL indexer.
If the requested URL was already reserved for another redirect, then Magento will create this url with a `-1` appended.

If you delete that rewrite from the core_url_rewrite table and reindex that issue should go away.

You Can access all the rewrites from the admin under `Catalog=>URL Rewrite Management` - Select the redirect you're looking for, click into it and then you can delete it.

Comment: Thank you! How do I access core_url_rewrite table?

Comment: updated answer - see above

Comment: When searching for the URL www.theidleman.com/brands/carhartt-1.html can't be found?